# How to Format C-printf string to be equal to bash-printf string

Tags: c, bash, printf

I want to send timestamps via the CAN interface for analysis. 
Therefore I used the cansend from the Linux-can/can-utils. On the Linux shell I can send the current time via 
`cansend can0 123#$(printf "%x" $(date +%s%N))`.

`date +%s%N` gives me the output `1566378614461677537`  (which is 19 digits) simply converted to hex with `printf "%X" $(date +%s%N)` gives me the desired output `B15CE567BA9D338E` (which is 8 Bytes CAN-frame)
which then is sent with the "cansend". On the other side, inside my C-Code

```c
    struct timeval start; 
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    printf("%.0f%.0f\n", (double)( start.tv_sec) , (double)(start.tv_usec)); //for debug
    printf("%x%.0X.%0X%X\n", (double)(start.tv_sec), (double)(start.tv_usec)); //desired output
```

gives me the output `1566382713648209`
(that's 16 digits without nano, but accurate enought for me) but if i use 
`printf("%x%.0X%0X%X\n", (double)(start.tv_sec), (double)(start.tv_usec))` then the output is `09E40000041D757460`. 
How can I get the desired output `B15CE567BA9D338E`?

Comment: Why are you passing values cast to `double` to a `printf()` with formatting strings `%x`  and `%X`? Those expect `unsigned int`, so this is instant undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Just convert it then to hexadecimal value with nanoseconds resolution...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct timespec tp;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
    unsigned long long tmp = tp.tv_sec * 1000ull * 1000 * 1000 + tp.tv_nsec;
    printf("%llX", tmp);
}
```

Don't use gettimeofday, it's deprecated since POSIX 2008.